# Como se cuantas coincidencias tengo en una lista - JS

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente pregunta, tengo un select con varios elementos y una función filtro. Eso me funciona bien, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de acomodar dinámicamente el size del select en función de las coincidencias.
No se me ocurre otra forma mas que la plateada.

Muchas gracias!!

```
<div>
 <div>
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" style="margin: 10px;width: 165px;" onkeyup="filter()">
 </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="select" size="20">
                        <option>Cupcake</option>
                        <option>Cunut</option>
                        <option>Eclair</option>
                        <option>Froyo</option>
                        <option>Gingerbread</option>
                        <option>Honeycomb</option>
                        <option>Ice Cream Sandwich</option>
                        <option>Jelly Bean</option>
                        <option>Kitkat</option>
                        <option>Lollipop</option>
                        <option>Marshmallow</option>
                        <option>Nougat</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <script>
                function filter(){
                    var keyword = document.getElementById("search").value;
                    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    
                    for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
                        var txt = select.options[i].text;
                        txt = txt.toLowerCase(); 
                        if (!txt.match(keyword)) {
                            select.options[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                            select.options[i].setAttribute("hidden", "hidden"); 
                            select.size = "4"; 
                        } else {
                            select.options[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
                            select.options[i].removeAttribute("hidden"); 
                            select.size = "1"; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta (explicaciones más abajo):

```js
function filter() {
  var keyword = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  let coincidencias = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    var txt = select.options[i].text.toLowerCase();
    if (txt.includes(keyword)) {
      coincidencias += 1
      select.options[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
      select.options[i].removeAttribute("hidden");
    } else {
      select.options[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      select.options[i].setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    }
  }
  if (coincidencias > 0) {
    select.removeAttribute("hidden");
    select.size = coincidencias;
    errorMsg.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    select.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    errorMsg.innerHTML = "No hay coincidencias!!"
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" style="margin: 10px;width: 165px;" onkeyup="filter()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="errorMsg"></div>
    <select id="select" size="20">
      <option>Cupcake</option>
      <option>Cunut</option>
      <option>Eclair</option>
      <option>Froyo</option>
      <option>Gingerbread</option>
      <option>Honeycomb</option>
      <option>Ice Cream Sandwich</option>
      <option>Jelly Bean</option>
      <option>Kitkat</option>
      <option>Lollipop</option>
      <option>Marshmallow</option>
      <option>Nougat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Explicación de los cambios

- He creado un nuevo `<div>` con el id **errMsg** en el HTML para reservar un espacio donde colocar un mensaje de error en caso de que no haya coincidencias.
- He convertido tanto la variable **keyword** como la variable **txt** a minúsculas con [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) para la comparación posterior (en tu caso te habias olvidado de hacerlo en el **keyword**).
- He inicializado una nueva variable denominada **coincidencias** que contendrá el total de coincidencias encontradas, antes del bucle.

```
let coincidencias = 0
```

- He cambiado `select.length` por `select.options.length` básicamente porque no me funcionaba bien, je
- He cambiado el método [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) por el [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) porque **match()** está orientado a expresiones regulares, y aquí no hacia falta.
- En cada coincidencia encontrada he sumado 1 a la variable **coincidencias**

```
coincidencias += 1
```

- Ya fuera del bucle, compruebo el total de coincidencias encontradas en un condicional, y si son más de 0 (valor inicial) fuerzo la aparación del **select** y asigno al atributo **size** del **select** el número de coincidencias encontradas (eso es lo que mejor responde a tu pregunta).  También fuerzo que desaparezca el mensaje de error si existe:

```
        select.removeAttribute("hidden");
        select.size = coincidencias;
        errorMsg.innerHTML = '';
```

- En caso de que no haya coincidencias escondo el **select** y muestro el mensaje de error en el div con el id **errorMsg**:

```
        select.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
        errorMsg.innerHTML = "No hay coincidencias!!"
```

Comment: Genial masterguru, me sirvió bastante!! Consulta, el match y el include funcionarían de la misma forma??

Comment: @MatiasAllegranza Acabo de poner una explicación donde también comento lo del **match()**.  Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberías marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio!

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahí la marqué.